# Makefile wait if the file exists

Tags: makefile, wait

I am trying this command:

```
if [ -f "${FOO}"]; then \
    sleep 5; \
fi
```

But I see an error like this:
/bin/sh: line 0: [: missing `]'

Can someone explain this to me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can someone please explain me the difference between                                                       1. (while [ -e "${VAR_FILE}" ]; do echo "test successful" ; done)  and  2. (while [ -e ${VAR_FILE} ]; do echo "test successful" ; done)

Comment: The main difference is when `VAR_FILE` is not defined or contains spaces, which would resolve to 0 or more words when used without the quotes, leading either to syntax error or incorrect existence check.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I was missing a space: 
OLD: if [ -f "${FOO}"]; then \
NEW: if [ -f "${FOO}" ]; then \